# Permutation certification. A cryptographic hash function for permutations?

Tags: permutations, cryptography

Alice has a secret permutation $\alpha$ (a random permutation of an $n$-set; $n=18$ would be a decent choice for the application I have in mind).  She wants to convince Bob that she has $\alpha$, but doesn't want to tell him what $\alpha$ is.

Fortunately, they prepared for this in advance.  When $\alpha$ was initially generated, a certificate $c(\alpha)$ was given to Bob.  So, Alice computes $c(\alpha)$ and sends it to Bob, and Bob checks it against his version, thereby verifying that Alice indeed has $\alpha$.

> *Q*: What is a good choice of certification function $c$?

I don't need 100% surety here.  But it needs to be unlikely that Debbie (who does not know $\alpha$) can guess what $c(\alpha)$ is (thereby convincing Bob that she has $\alpha$ when she doesn't).

Schemes that are not particularly satisfying:

- Obviously $c(\alpha)=\alpha$ is not a good choice: it reveals to Bob what $\alpha$ is.
- If $c$ is "the number of fixed points" function, then Debbie would have a reasonable chance (asymptotically $\frac{1}{e}$ ([link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html))) of guessing correctly by choosing $0$ (convincing Bob that she has $\alpha$, when she does not).  It also gives Bob partial information about what $\alpha$ is.
- It would be possible to use some kind of [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), but using something like MD5 or a SHA seems like overkill for this application.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a cryptographic hash function here?

Comment: Mostly because the output would be long (this limits its applications in cases where hardware might be restricted).  Depending on what turns up, I'd also like to generalize to a many-party scheme, but it might be difficult to store a lot of hash values.